# Langchain inheriting from BaseTool

Tags: python, oop, langchain

I'm using langchain agents with some custom tools, following the documentation I wrote a class that's responsible for making http requests to an endpoint. The code for it looks like this:

```
from langchain.tools import BaseTool

class Tool1(BaseTool):
    
    name = "..."
    description = "..."

    def __init__(self, headers):
        BaseTool.__init__(self)
        self.header = headers
        self.__url = "..."
        
    
    def _run(
        self, category: str, run_manager: Optional[CallbackManagerForToolRun] = None
    ) -> str:
        """Use the tool"""
        
        #make the request
        
        
    
    async def _arun(
        self, query: str, run_manager: Optional[AsyncCallbackManagerForToolRun] = None
    ) -> str:
        """Use the tool asynchronously."""
        raise NotImplementedError("custom_search does not support async")
```

The problem is that when I try to instantiate Tool1 it raises a ValueError saying: "Tool1" object has no field "header". I don't see what's wrong with the **init**() method.